# How to align image and unordered list horizontally?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to align an image at the right side of unordered list. So the contact info is displayed on the left side.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/map.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="info"><b>Address</b></div>
                    <div class="sub-info">72 John Doe area</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/email.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="info"><b>Email</b></div>
                    <div class="sub-info">email@domain.com</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="icon"><img src="images/phone.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="info"><b>Phone</b></div>
                    <div class="sub-info">732-757-2923</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/location.png" alt="">
</div><!-- contact -->
```

Below is the code where i used table alignment for list elements as shown above in the HTML code.

**CSS**

```
#contact{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5% 5% 5% 12.5%;
}
#contact ul{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#contact li{
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.icon, .info, .sub-info{
    display: table-cell;
}
.info, .sub-info{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon, .info{
    width: 80px;
}
```

Image for more clarity

[image]

Comment: what about float:right;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;
```

on both your `<ul>` and `<img>` elements. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7XUh/1/

You'd need to adjust a little for your specific image/icon sizes, but you get the idea.

Comment: Image has aligned to right but it breaks the alignment of li elements

Comment: Updated the fiddle to better match your sample image: http://jsfiddle.net/U7XUh/1/ Make sure your frame is wide enough so `li` elements don't wrap. You can adjust this better when you paste the code in your actual page.

Comment: adding float:right to .map-image class improves it further. As i wasn't able to adjust the margin of ul and image separately earlier.